# Problems changing contents of bashrc?

Tags: gedit, dbus

I have installed NS2 (using Ubuntu 13.04)
Tried to update Path and Library Path using command gedit .bashrc but getting the following error.

```
** (gedit:3732): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-UnpdNFJM8M: Connection refused.
(gedit:3732): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported.
```

can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't have the rep to leave a quick suggestion to try `sudo` & `nano` as comment, I'll do my best to answer your question.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter

```
gksu gedit /your/path/to/.bashrc
```

if that doesn't open, there's something deeply wrong worthy of some troubleshooting.  However, you can by pass it for now using nano, in a terminal type:

```
sudo nano /your/path/to/.bashrc
```

if you are trying to edit the .bashrc for the user you are logged in as then simply

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

should work

To exit and save in nano press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> then <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know about the kbd mark-up!!; not sure why some mods are rejecting it, I'll change on my end.  Thanks Braiam!

Comment: Problem solved.just a beginner.Having a great feeling.Thanks